# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `}'

Tags: unix

I have below command which is working fine if I hard code the values -

```
find . -name '*txt' -exec bash -c ' mv $0 ${0/\7777/4444}' {} \;
```

it replace `4444` with `7777`

But when I trying by passing value using variable with double quotes, it is not working -

```
SourceString1=7777 and TargetString1=4444
find . -name '*txt' -exec bash -c ' mv "{$0}" "${0/\"${SourceString1}"/"${TargetString1}"}"' {} \;
```

Comment: Don't use nested double-quotes: `"${0/\"${SourceString1}"/"${TargetString1}"}"` - This will cause problems. Instead, if you must nest quotes inside each other, use single quotes inside double-quotes, so your `find` command would look like this: `find . -name '*txt' -exec bash -c 'mv "{$0}" "${0/\'${SourceString1}'/'${TargetString1}'}"' {} \;`

Comment: Thanks for quick response !

Comment: @peter or @PeterSmith  I have made changes as per your comments but now it giving error -
mv: cannot stat `{./Dnamefile.txt}': No such file or directory

Comment: That means the `mv` command can't move the file because it doesn't exist. It may be saying that because the user running the command doesn't have access to read/write the file, but more likely is that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @ResetACK   I have made changes as per your comments but now it giving error -
mv: cannot stat `{./Dnamefile.txt}': No such file or directory

Comment: @ResetACK .. Thanks .. I am running this command in my home directory and I can see multiple .txt file as well. Also when I am using hard coded values in place of variable it is working fine.